# Magento server side form validation

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

is there any server side form validation in magento? i have created a from and using magentos form validation but its not gonna work if someone disable the javascipt and enters something that can be harmful. if there is no built in class for that. could someone please point me in a direction how to implement a server side form validation as a backup. here is my my code for the form

```
<div style="border:0px solid red; margin:0px auto;">

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>


<form id="test" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('pricenotify/pricenotify/db') ?>" method="post">

            <label for="price">Price *</label>
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="" class="required-entry validate-number"/><br />
            <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" class="required-entry validate-email"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="propri" name="propri" value="<?php echo $_product->getPrice() ?>" />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" onclick="if(customForm.validator && customForm.validator.validate()) this.form.request(); return false;" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//< ![CDATA[
var customForm = new VarienForm('test',false);
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep it simple, you could do the validation in your controller

```
try {
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!Zend_Validate::is($postObject->getPrice(), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is($postObject->getEmail(), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if ($error) {
                throw new Exception();
            }


            //save to db

            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('pricenotify')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            $this->_redirect('/');

            return;
        }
```

Zend_Validate : http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.validate.html

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer It helped me

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Magento has server-side validation for some forms. However, the module that added the form is responsible for validating it - so if you're dealing with third-party code like a plugin, it might not be there.

Conventionally, the validation code lives with the Model part of a module. For example, in Magento's built-in review functionality, when a review form is submitted, its data is validated by the `validate()` function in the `/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Review.php` file. I'd start by looking at that code, and the code in existing Mage/Core modules for examples.

In the situation that you give, the conventional place for the validation logic would be `/app/code/local/YourCompany/PriceNotify/Model/Pricenotify.php`

Answer (score -5):

Magento uses prototype to validate forms.  To implement this validation, just add "required-entry" to your input tag.

Comment: the OP explicitely asks for server side validation. Prototype is only js and client-side (and also really **not** secure)